# Programmatically Approve DocuSign document

Tags: docusignapi

Soon after my user signs a DocuSign envelope, I want to be able to quickly approve or deny it. Referring to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765072/why-recipient-action-acknowledge-receipt-cannot-approve-decline-in-docusign) and [this forum post](https://community.docusign.com/t5/Managing-Documents/No-way-to-correct-completed-documents/td-p/12157), I've added myself as a Signer (as well as the Sender, I suppose) and created an Approve tag for my role.

This works fine, but since the circumstances in which I want to reject/void a given document are both rare and trivial to check, I'd rather not approve them manually. I see that there's a way to void the envelope via the API, but how can I *approve* it via the API? Or is there some better way to accomplish this whole thing?

Comment: My current best solution is to delete myself as a Recipient of the envelope, if I want to Approve it (there _is_ a way to do this via the API). Then, assuming my user already signed it, the envelope will mark itself as completed. But there must be a better way.

Comment: Your workaround is the only way you'd be able to automatically "approve" a document inside of DocuSign or via the API.

Comment: This saddens me. But you sound confident enough that I'll post it as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current best solution is to delete myself as a Recipient of the envelope, if I want to Approve it (there *is* a way to do this via the API). Then, assuming my user already signed it, the envelope will mark itself as completed.